# Trying to display tweets, issues with JSON & Java

Tags: android, json, twitter

I'm simply trying to get all tweets from a certain hashtag and display them in a list view on Android. Ive got some code that doesnt get any errors but when I run the application, Android just closes unexpectedly, I think this could be where the majority of the problems lie:

```
public ArrayList<Tweet> getTweets(String searchTerm, int page) throws JSONException {
    String searchUrl = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=@" 
                        + searchTerm + "&rpp=100&page=" + page;

    ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<Tweet>();

    HttpClient client = new  DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(searchUrl);

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    String responseBody = null;
    try{
        responseBody = client.execute(get, responseHandler);
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    JSONParser parser=new JSONParser();

    try {
        Object obj = parser.parse(responseBody);
        jsonObject=(JSONObject)obj;

    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.v("TEST","Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    JSONArray arr = null;

    try {
        Object j = jsonObject.get("results");
        arr = (JSONArray)j;
    }catch(Exception ex){
        Log.v("TEST","Exception: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
           JSONObject t = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
           Tweet tweet = new Tweet(
             t.get("from_user").toString(),
             t.get("text").toString(),
             t.get("profile_image_url").toString()
           );
           tweets.add(tweet);
         }

    return tweets;
}
```

Or when the code initializes

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.info_main_layout);

    ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = null;
    try {
        tweets = getTweets("android", 1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewId);
    listView.setAdapter(new UserItemAdapter(this, R.layout.info_layout, tweets));
}

public class UserItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Tweet> {
    private ArrayList<Tweet> tweets;

    public UserItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Tweet> tweets) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, tweets);
        this.tweets = tweets;
    }
```

In The DDMS I get these compile errors:

03-23 16:14:02.253: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.uwe.bus/com.uwe.bus.InfoActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at com.uwe.bus.InfoActivity.getTweets(InfoActivity.java:133)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at com.uwe.bus.InfoActivity.onCreate(InfoActivity.java:39)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)

03-23 16:14:02.263: E/AndroidRuntime(215): ... 11 more

Line 39:

```
ArrayList<tweet> tweets = null;
try {
tweets = getTweets("android", 1);
} catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Line 133:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
JSONObject t = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);
Tweet tweet = new Tweet(
t.get("from_user").toString(),
t.get("text").toString(),
t.get("profile_image_url").toString()
);
tweets.add(tweet);
}
```

The first error looks like it comes from the Manifest.xml but the manifest is spotless, so I don't get it.

Or does anyone know an easier way to just display tweets in android...

Answer (score 0):

If that for loop is Line 133.

Your `arr` variable has not been instantiated and is null